# If author edits his question right after it's asked, does it appear in the revision history?

Tags: discussion, editing

Example is [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77501/how-to-exclude-a-field-when-a-search-is-done/77504) - I answered it, hit submit, then I've seen a glimpse of standard "an edit has been made". Now I don't see any edit history, but there is last line in a question I'm sure wasn't there at the beginning. Is it supposed to work that way? If so, when? Or am I going crazy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you're not going crazy, there's a 5 minute grace period on editing:

> **Grace period**
>
> In order to prevent a series of tiny edits from showing up in the revision history, a single user who edits a post is given a 5-minute grace period. During this period, any additional edits they make are collapsed into the same edit in the revision history, displaying only the final outcome of all their edits within that 5 minute period. The grace period ends after exactly 5 minutes, but also ends if another user edits the post, at which time *their* grace period begins.

Source: [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) on Meta.SO

Comment: I was searching for specific thing and missed general answer covering this one topic. Sorry.

Comment: @Mołot,  this 5 min grace period will change the whole concept of the question, i think the answered users also need to be intimated, when an edit made to the question.

Comment: @Bala Now it seems it's not worth answering before 5 minutes passed since question was asked. At least then something will stay in edit history.

Comment: @Mołot +1 subscribing or at least intimation

Comment: @Bala In reality that happens so rarely that it's not worth defining a case for. In these rare occurrences just suck it up and move on :) In either case this is a network-wide feature so if your opinion is that things need to change...open a feature request on Meta.SO and have at it!

Comment: @Mołot I dont think you can wait for 5 mins on all SE sites ;)